# Edit Position a little div inside another resizable div without disturbing the container's contents

Tags: jquery, css, html, positioning, resizable

I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/asaakius/5nGYS/7/

You'll notice this little div `$(#menu)` with the letter "v", if I remove this div, the textarea and textbox are aligned as needed, and resizing takes place with the position of both divs totally in-sync.

But it gets messed up when I add the `$(#menu)` div. I just want the little menu div to be inside the upper right corner of `$(#textarea)`, without disturbing the text inside it, and without disturbing the alignment of `$(#textarea)` and `$(#textbox)`. What I mean is, I want it to be visible above the text, like as if it had a higher z-index (it's the beginning of a small menu).

### Edit

I just realized that if I keep menu's position:absolute, it stays in the container. But how to keep it on the right side? I want it to be consistently positioned in the upper right corner, regardless of resizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the style of #menu to:

```
#menu{ right: 0; color:red; position:absolute; }​
```

`Float:right` causes the next div to flow around it, `position:absolute;` causes it to be taken out of the flow completely.

Comment: Thanks, i realized that a few seconds before you posted, and I've edited my question. I still need to position it on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overlap position of a div with relative to have a higher z-index. You have to use position:absolute on your menu div. and make right:0; to stick to the right. Optionally apply higher z-index to a menu div. see example: http://jsfiddle.net/5nGYS/10/

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you can use `position` to `relative` if you modify your layout.

```
<div id="textbox" class="textbox" style="top: 10px; left: 10px;">
  <span id='menu'>v</span>
  <span Hello there
</div>
```

With a zero-ed `border` and `padding`.

```
#menu {
  ...
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}​
```